# Homebrew: install stuck on Checking for Sudo access

Tags: command-line, homebrew, sudo

I just started The Odin Project, I've had one lesson in command line, and only 28% of the way into foundations.

I'm on Setting up Git, Step 1.0: Install Homebrew

First, you’ll need to install Homebrew. Make sure you have checked the requirements here. Once you meet the requirements, copy and paste the following into your terminal:
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

After copy and pasting into my terminal it got stuck on "Checking for Sudo access." Not sure what to do? Can I temporarily disable admin password requirement to install homebrew?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogMSk.png)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, So I figured it out.

1. Enter: sudo /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
2. Enter password
3. reentered: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Then it installed no problem. Thought I'd leave this up for any other newbies that have the same problem as me.

[-Vincit qui se vincit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiYJd.png)

Comment: I have no idea why but my strangely provisioned corporate MacBook finally let me install with this tip. I still got prompted for my pw numerous times throughout the install, but at least it worked. Run with sudo once, it tells me not to run it as root and then run without sudo - it works ?!?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, in the article previous to installing Homebrew, TOP says you wont be able to see the keys for your password, to protect your security. That being said, type in your password without error and hit enter. It will continue the installation without you needing to reenter the install code in terminal.